# Loop through list of links (return on main page)

Tags: java, selenium

My goal is to click on each link from list, take specific text from new opened page (which contains table), then return on previous page (main page which contains all links), open second link and so on...
As I'm relatively new in Java selenium **I don't now how to return on main** **page and continue with looping** (after collecting info from first opened page).

I'm trying with this code but this error occurs: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up
Command duration or timeout: 10.04 seconds

```
     package expofair;

     import java.util.Iterator;
     import java.util.List;
     import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

     import org.openqa.selenium.By;
     import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
     import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
     import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

     public class exponull {

     public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

     WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
     driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

           // go to main page

    driver.get(mainpage);
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();

            // list of all links     

    List<WebElement> lista1 = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".tl.nobr>a"));
    Iterator<WebElement> iter = lista1.iterator();

    while(iter.hasNext()) {
    WebElement we = iter.next();
    we.click();
        String S1 = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#nm-date")).getText();
        System.out.println(S1);
    }


    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you change the DOM by going to another page or even refreshing the DOM the driver loose the WebElements it had and see new elements, even if the page is exactly the same. That what causes the `StaleElementReferenceException`.

You need to find the elements all over again each iteration:

```
List<WebElement> lista1 = null;
int size = 1;

for (int i = 0 ; i < size ; ++i) {
    lista1 = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".tl.nobr > a")); //locate all the links
    size = lista1.size(); //change the loop itreations number to the right one
    lista1.get(i).click(); //click on the link
    System.out.println(Sdriver.findElement(By.id("nm-date")).getText()); //print the data
    driver.navigate().back(); //go to previous page
}
```

Comment: Yeah. In a mean time I found similar solution also with for loop (updating the code after navigate back): driver.navigate().back();                          lista1= driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".tl.nobr>a"));  but your solution is better. Thank you.